# How to grep specific a word in bash

Tags: bash

I want to catch the word that is after "on" in several lines at a file, and if the word appears already in the file, I want to skip it.
I tried to do so:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "" > missig_packages.txt
cat log_file.txt | grep depends > dependsLog.txt
function createListOfPackages {
    if grep "$1" missig_packages.txt; then
        continue
    else
        echo "$1" >> missig_packages.txt
    fi  
}
while read line; do
    package=`cat dependsLog.txt | cut -d" " -f5`
    createListOfPackages $package
done < dependsLog.txt
```

The file dependsLog.txt contains lines like this:

```
  libgcc1:amd64 depends on **gcc-4.9-base** (= 4.9.1-0ubuntu1); however:
  cinder-volume depends on **cinder-common** (= 1:2015.1.1-0ubuntu2~cloud2); 
  python-cryptography depends on **python-cffi**.
  python-pycadf depends on **python-netaddr**.
```

How can I `grep` the words between `**` and `**` (which are not themselves in the text)? Each line begins with "".

Comment: Sure you don't want to call that file `missing_packages.txt` (with an 'n') instead?

Answer (score 3):

this is awk's jobs.

line with on

```
awk '$3 == "on" '
```

the word you are looking for

```
awk '$3 == "on" { print $4 ;}'
```

- `$3 == "on"` will get the line with "on" as third word
- `{ print $4 ;}` will print fourth word

Answer (score 1):

Try following command which will grep word after 'on' from dependLogs.txt and then will insert "" at start of line.

```
cat dependsLog.txt | grep -oP "(?<=on )[^ ]+" | sed 's/^/\"\"/' >> missig_packages.txt
```

To make sure lines do not get duplicated you can sort and uniq by following command.

```
cat dependsLog.txt | grep -oP "(?<=on )[^ ]+" | sed 's/^/\"\"/' | sort | uniq >> missig_packages.txt
```

Comment: 1) ` cat foo | grep  pattern | ...`  can be replace by   `grep  pattern foo | ...` 2) ` sort | uniq ` can be replaced by ` sort  -u `.

Answer (score 1):

Your entire shell script fragment can be replaced with:

```
awk '/depends on/ { print $4}' log_file.txt | sed -e 's/\.$//' | sort -u > missing_packages.txt
```

The sed script strips the trailing `.` from package names where the input line doesn't have version information.

Comment: Or just `awk '/depends on/ {  sub(/\.$/, "", $4); print $4 }' log_file.txt | sort -u > missing_packages.txt`

Comment: True, and that's a valuable addition to my answer but it's easier for a novice like the OP to understand a simple pipeline using multiple tools.  Your version would be the next step after understanding the simple version - understanding comes first, optimisation later.